# Trouble routing settings

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

```
To access http://taobao.com/index/index/cityid/1 point http://taobao.com/Alaska 
To access http://taobao.com/index/index/cityid/2 point http://taobao.com/Houston
To access http://taobao.com/index/index/cityid/3 point http://taobao.com/NewYork
To access http://taobao.com/index/index/cityid/3 point http://taobao.com/LosAngeles
```

.......
Nearly 100 cities.
route.ini which write

```
[production]
routes.rating.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.BeiJing.route = "BeiJing"
routes.BeiJing.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.BeiJing.defaults.action = "index"
```

How to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.add-config) section of the Zend Framework manual should point you in the right direction.

An example route might look like this:

> routes.alaska.route = "Alaska"
>   routes.alaska.defaults.controller = index
>   routes.alaska.defaults.action = index
>   routes.alaska.defaults.cityid = 1

This solution is quite restrictive though - perhaps if you can detail what you're trying to achieve, myself or my fellow contributors here may be able to offer up a better solution?